# Java - How to load the full source of an HTML website

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I am trying to load the FULL source code of an HTML website into a `String` in Java. I have tried several approaches, however, I get almost all the source code. To make it worse: one of the main parts that I do not get is the part that I need the most!

Comment: You have our sympathy, but you won't be getting much else until you show us your code and explain in more detail the nature of the content you are not receiving.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far and explain in more detail.?

Comment: Is the HTML website publicly available? If so, can you post a link?

Comment: Contact the website's author and ask them for the source. seriously though, are you referring to the HTML source or the source code of the HTML website?

Comment: If that code you need is created dynamically, using DOM manipulation, then you actually need Javascript engine to generate it. Vanilla Java cannot do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.website.com");
URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();

//Spoof the connection so we look like a web browser
spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0;    H010818)" );
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
String strLine = "";
String finalHTML = "";
//Loop through every line in the source
while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
   finalHTML += strLine;
}
```

Comment: I see a Mozilla option there. Does this ONLY work if you have Mozilla? I want this to work for the vast-majority of web browsers.

Comment: No, you're just pretending that you're using a Mozilla browser, so it looks like you're a legitimate user browsing the site.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Let me test this out.

Answer (score 5):

It might be because the content you are looking for is actually loaded dynamically, through ajax/javascript.

for example, a website might contain an empty DIV tag, which would be populated with many things only after the page loads (Through an AJAX call to another location).

Comment: In this case, there is a big chance that `HtmlUnit` or similar library will be able to handle those dynamic contents.